# XCode 4.3.3 crashes on launch running 10.7.4

Tags: xcode4

After installing the latest preview version of Xcode my other install of Xcode 4.3.3 started crashing on launch.  I'm running OS X Lion 10.7.4.  Here is the crash that I get after opening Xcode for a few seconds.

```
    Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4E3002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-1193/Framework/Classes/Model/Logging/ActivityLog/IDEActivityLogSection.m:666
Details:  Assertion failed: _uniqueIdentifier
Object:   <IDEActivityLogSection: 0x40797e340>
Method:   -dvt_initFromDeserializer:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40797e700>{name = (null), num = 19}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000106967b9f -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x0000000105e225d5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010643aac3 -[IDEActivityLogSection dvt_initFromDeserializer:] (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x0000000105df4085 -[DVTSimplePlainTextDeserializer decodeObject] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000105df4888 -[DVTSimplePlainTextDeserializer decodeObjectList] (in DVTFoundation)
  5  0x000000010643a455 -[IDEActivityLogSection dvt_initFromDeserializer:] (in IDEFoundation)
  6  0x0000000105df4085 -[DVTSimplePlainTextDeserializer decodeObject] (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x0000000106489b2b +[IDEActivityLogSection sectionWithContentsOfFile:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x000000010643a27d -[IDEOnDiskActivityLogRecord fullLogWithError:] (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x0000000106500b31 __45-[IDEBuildIssueProvider _blueprintsDidChange]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
 10  0x00007fff8afb8ae1 -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff8af7f6b4 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)
 12  0x00007fff8af92912 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 (in Foundation)
 13  0x00007fff87df7a86 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff87df8965 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff866e33da _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff866e4b85 start_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
```

Answer (score 10):

Finally I was able to get it to launch by doing the following.

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Delete everything in the above directory

Hold down Option and double-click on the XCode icon.  You'll see a popup that asks if you want to restore the windows from your last session.  Hit don't restore.

Now Xcode 4.3.3 seems to be launching

Comment: You don't actually need to delete everything. Just delete derived data folder of the project you are working on. This fixed the problem for me. Thx @ribeto! ;)

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem with my Xcode 4.3.3 upon installing 4.4.1. I have removed both ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and my projects derived data folder but none seem to work.

Comment: Now i deleted my build folder and changed build location settings to 'legacy'. seems to be working now :)